# JPQL query to join multiple tables

Tags: jpql

i am quite new to JPQL, i have 3 entity class Book,Loan,member, relationship
Loan-Book(@OneToOne)unidirection
Loan-Member(@OneToMany)unidirectional

snippet from my loan class

```
public class loan implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String dateofissue;
    private String dueDate; 

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bookid")
    private book Bookid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="member_ID")
    private member memberid;
```

when i write a very simple query "Select Loan from loan loan"; i get all the columns including columns member and books because of the relation

how can i write a JPQL query to return selected column book.title,book.id,loan.duedate,member.firstname,member.id from book,loan,member

the purpose of the query is to retrive all the borrowed books, by all member

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You already have mappings define so just directly reference them in JPQL.

```
select l.Bookid.title, l.Bookid.id, loan.duedate, l.memberid.firstname, 
l.memberid.id from loan l;
```

or you can create aliases also for shorter name.

```
select book.title, book.id, loan.duedate, member.firstname, member.id 
from loan l join l.Book book join l.Member member;
```

Comment: do i have to map these output in some way, because i am getting a nullpointerexception@Override
 public List<loan> getLoandBooks() {
 Query q= em.createQuery("select book.title, book.id, loan.duedate, member.firstname, member.id from loan l join l.Book book join l.Member member");
 return q.getResultList();
 }

Comment: Do you have some data in loan table ?

Comment: yup, 1 have one record in book table, one in member table and one in loan table, when doing "Select Loan from loan loan" i get all the column from all the tables that are in relationship

Comment: @Override
 public List<loan> getLoandBooks() {
   Query q= em.createQuery("select l.Bookid.title, l.Bookid.id, loan.duedate, l.memberid.firstname, l.memberid.id from loan l");
 return q.getResultList();
 }